# Leaflet.PolylineOffset Polyline drawing issue

Tags: polygon, leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I don't have much experience with `Leaflet JS` and I'm using `Leaflet.PolylineOffset` in order to draw a polyline around a polygon:

```
L.polygon(coords, { fillColor: 'white', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight: 20, color: 'white', opacity: 0.5, fill: true}).addTo(map);
coords.push(coords[0]);
L.polyline(coords, { color: 'white', weight: 2, opacity: 0.7, fill: false, offset: 10}).addTo(map);
```

And my coordinates are

```
var coords= [
[27.41059824690096,-82.4097625234208],
[27.41010163347799,-82.4089700231027],
[27.411940517407686,-82.40990955739109],
[27.409994283095067,-82.41053391174971]
];
```

But my issue is that it overlaps the polyline segments at the bottom of my polyline like
[image: ![enter image description here]

but the line should be following the polygon shape.

Is there a way to avoid this overlapping with `Leaflet.PolylineOffset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about the `Leaflet.PolylineOffset` repository, but another way would be to use [`turf`](https://turfjs.org/) using the [`buffer`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) and [`polygonToLine`](https://turfjs.org/docs/#polygonToLine) functions. The difference would be that the polyline would not change with the zoom-level. If that is needed you could run a function when the zoom-level changes and recalculate the buffer every time.

See: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn1zfu57/1/)

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([27.41059824690096,-82.4097625234208], 17);
L.tileLayer(
  'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: `&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> Contributors`,
    maxZoom: 18,
}).addTo(map);

const coords= [
  [27.41059824690096,-82.4097625234208],
  [27.41010163347799,-82.4089700231027],
  [27.411940517407686,-82.40990955739109],
  [27.409994283095067,-82.41053391174971]
];

const polygon = L.polygon(coords, { fillColor: 'white', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight: 20, color: 'white', opacity: 0.5, fill: true}).addTo(map);

// Create Polyline using polylineoffset
const polylineCoords = [...coords];
polylineCoords.push(polylineCoords[0]);
const polyline = L.polyline(polylineCoords, { color: 'red', weight: 2, opacity: 0.7, fill: false, offset: 20}).addTo(map);

// Create Polyline using turf.js
const buffer = turf.buffer(polygon.toGeoJSON(), 10, {units: 'meters'});
const bufferLine = turf.polygonToLine(buffer);
const bufferPolyline = L.geoJSON(bufferLine, {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {color: "green"};
    }
}).addTo(map)
```